# Angualar2 & Stylelint: Unexpected unknown pseudo-class selector ":host"

Tags: css, angular, host, pseudo-class, stylelint

How can I teach Stylelint Angular's selector ":host" ?

E.g. [Angular2-Seed by MGechev](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) shows in its build-process ":host" as error:

```
src/client/app/+home/home.component.css
1:1     ‼  Unexpected unknown pseudo-class selector 
        ":host" (selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown) [stylelint]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following [selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/tree/master/src/rules/selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown#ignorepseudoclasses-regex-string) rule definition:

```
{
"rules": {
  "selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown": [ true, {
    ignorePseudoClasses: ["host"],
  } ]
  }
}
```

Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39196050/1911294 for the new recommended approch

Comment: the option name has changed to `ignorePseudoElements` https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown#ignorepseudoelements-regex-string

Answer (score 3):

Support for the [CSS Scoping Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/#selectors) pseudo-classes and pseudo-element of `:host`, `:host-context` and `::slotted` was added in `stylelint@7.2.0`.

After updating to this version you should no longer need to use the `ignorePseudoClasses` optional secondary option.